# OSX: Building OpenCV 3.0.0, undeclared identifier clEnqueueSVMMap

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to get OpenCV built on OSX (Yosemite), following this guide: http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/

Got the static libs built fine but when building the shared libs I get errors, including the following:

> /Users/chrismash/Development/OSX/WireframeUpscaler/WireframeUpscaler/ThirdParty/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp:2700:49:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'clEnqueueSVMUnmap'; did you mean
>         'svm::SVMFunctions::fn_clEnqueueSVMUnmap'?   ...= clEnqueueSVMUnmap;
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>          svm::SVMFunctions::fn_clEnqueueSVMUnmap
>
> /Users/chrismash/Development/OSX/WireframeUpscaler/WireframeUpscaler/ThirdParty/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp:2700:49:
>   error: 
>         invalid use of non-static data member 'fn_clEnqueueSVMUnmap'
>               svmFunctions.fn_clEnqueueSVMUnmap = clEnqueueSVMUnmap;

Any ideas where I might be going wrong...?

Comment: When configuring with CMake, did you enable the `WITH_OPENCL_SVM` option? OS X doesn't support OpenCL 2.0 (yet), so this option should be set to `OFF`.

Comment: I deleted everything in the sharedlibs folder, closed CMake and started it again and it worked that time.. the WITH_OPENCL_SVM was unchecked this time round (not sure about before) so that could have been the problem, if it somehow got checked in the first place!

Comment: Shouldn't your title be corrected to read OpenCV not OpenCL?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I got a bit confused as they were both being mentioned all over the place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jprice pointed out it seems I somehow got the WITH_OPENCL_SVM option enabled in CMake. Because OS X doesn't support OpenCL 2.0 yet it should be unticked.